# How to display progress indicator in flutter when a certain condition is true?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have widget which return `CircularProgressIndicator()`

it shows on the circular mark upper left of screen.

However I want to put this as overlay and put at the center of screen.

I am checking widget list but I cant find what Widget should I use as overlay.

On which layer should I put this on??

For now my code is like this ,when loading it shows `CircularProgressIndicator` instead of ListView

However I want to put `CircularProgressIndicator()` on `ListView`

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(loading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      itemCount: articles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(articles[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

---

Thank you very much for answers.

I solve with stack Widget like this below.
At first I try to use overlay, but I bumped into some errors.
So, I use simply stack.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget tempWidget = new CircularProgressIndicator();
    if(loading) {
         tempWidget = new CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    else {
        tempWidget = new Center();//EmptyWidget
    }
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
          controller: _controller,
          itemCount: articles.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(articles[index].title),
              onTap: () => onTapped(context,articles[index].url),
            );
          },
        ),
        Center(
          child: tempWidget
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
```

Comment: if you want to `"put at the center of screen."` use `Center` then

Comment: I want to overlay this on the other Widget. in my case `ListView.`

Comment: In Listview cell ?

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        },
        itemCount: 10,
      ),
      Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          );
        },
        itemCount: 10,
      ),
     isLoading?  Container(child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )): Container(), //if isLoading flag is true it'll display the progress indicator
    ],
  )
```

or you can use futureBuilder or streamBuilder when loading data from somewhere and you want to change the ui depending on the state

Answer (score 2):

To overlay or position items on top of each other you would usually use a Stack widget or Overlay as described [here](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9). For your usecase I would recommend checking out the [modal progress hud package](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_progress_hud).

Comment: i would say that to overlay items one should use `Overlay.of()` / `OverlayState` stuff - if such specialized classes exist using a `Stack` is reinventing the wheel imho